# How to send data in 2 dimensional array with ajax to the php page and print each dimension separately?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

So,I have made a page that has multiple checkboxes. Fetching the data from check boxes, I am storing that data in 2dimensional array with jquery. my code looks like this,

htmlpage,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="12" value="something1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="15" value="something2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="16" value="something3">

<div id='answer'></div>
```

...
JQ

```
var data =[];

.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (){ 
  data.push($(this).val(),$(this).attr('price'));   
}); 

what i am saving in data when consoled is like this,

output :["Corn Bhel","15","Corn Tikki chat","15","Corn Dahi Puri","15"]
```

sending this to ajax.,

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'check.php',
     dataType: 'html',
     data:'data='+data,
     success: function(data){
         $('.answer').html(data)
     }
 });
```

so the output which i expect should be like this

they both should be in the different array in php page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive the result as

```
$prices = [15,15];
$goods = ["Corn Bhel","Corn Tikki chat"];
```

You may do it by this way:

```
var prices = [];
var goods = [];

// push prices and values to the different arrays
$.each($.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),function(){
  goods.push($(this).val());
  prices.push($(this).attr('price'));
})

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:8888/1.php',
  dataType: 'html',
  // Send data with two different properties
  data:{prices:prices,goods:goods},
  success: function(data){
     $('.answer').html(data)
  }  
});
```

And on backend you will receive it in $_POST:

```
<?php

$prices = $_POST['prices'];
$goods = $_POST['goods'];

print_r($prices);
print_r($goods);
```

Test:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 16
)
Array
(
    [0] => something2
    [1] => something3
)
```

But on this way you may have some troubles with linkage good<->price on client side (if some price or good will be empty, for example), so better way is to aggregate your request to two-dimensional array:

```
var items = [];

$.each($.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),function(){
  items.push({
    good:$(this).val(),
    price:$(this).attr('price')
  });
})

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:8888/1.php',
  dataType: 'html',
  data:{items:items},
  success: function(data){
     $('.answer').html(data)
  }  
});
```

In that case you can read array of "models" on server side:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

Test:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [good] => something2
                    [price] => 15
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [good] => something3
                    [price] => 16
                )

        )

)
```

This variant is more safe because you will work with ready 'models', not with raw set of properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help,kindly lemme know if it works

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#alldetails").submit(function(e){
var dataa ={};
e.preventDefault();
$("#alldetails input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
  //data.push($(this).val(),$(this).attr('price'));   
  var valu=$(this).val();
  var price=$(this).attr('price');
  dataa[valu]=price;
  
});
console.log(dataa);/*{
  "something1": "12",
  "something2": "15",
  "something3": "16"
  this send the value as array key pair
  
}*/
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'check.php',
     dataType: 'html',
     data:{dataa:dataa},
     success: function(data){
         $('.answer').html(data)
     }
 });

//in your php
/*

<?php
$values=$_POST['dataa'];

foreach($values as $key=>$value){
echo "$key -> $value <br>";//this echos something1->12
}
?>
*/


})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="alldetails">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="12" value="something1">Something1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="15" value="something2">Something2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]"  price="16" value="something3">Something3
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>

<div id='answer'></div>
```